# ASP.NET not found returns 302 code instead of 404

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have ASP.NET V4 web application.
in my web.config I have:

`<customErrors mode="On">
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="Error.aspx" />
            <error statusCode="500" redirect="Error.aspx" />
        </customErrors>`

But when I am trying to get a page that doesnt exist, I see in the firebug I get error 302 (FOUND) and redirection to the homepage.
I dont get the 404...

What is it???

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Response code 302](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) is instructing your browser to redirect to another page.

Presumably this is because you put redirect="Error.aspx" in there when you get a 404.

This allows you to put in a pretty not-found page while breaking the HTML spec.